# Loading form from Application to Default module

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to change my files and forms to a modular structure.

Before they were at "application/forms" and the name was Application_Form_Example, now I'm moving to the default module (application/modules/default/forms) but I dont know how to name the form. If I leave it like "Application_Form_Example" I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_Example' not found in ..

The same if I change the name to "Default_Form_Example" or "Form_Example"

Is it necesary to call a Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader from bootstrap or how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

dimirc,

the standard naming convention for a modular form is similar to the following:

```
class Administration_Form_ManageContent extends Zend_Form
```

In this example "Administration" is the name of the module and "ManageContent" is form's name. The other thing to remember, which I see a lot of people overlooking, is that when you migrate to a modular structure, you need to include a module-specific bootstrap. They don't have to include much. Take the following for example:

```
<?php

class Administration_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Note that it extends from **Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap**, not Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap.

I hope this helps.

Matt

Comment: But what about the "Default" module? If I follow the convention I still cannot load it.

Comment: dimirc, You should just prefix your class with 'Default_'.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, there were three steps required:

1. In `application/configs/application.ini`, add the line:

   `resources.modules[] =`
2. In `application/modules/default/forms/ManageContent`, a class named `Default_Form_ManageContent`.
3. In `application/modules/default/Bootstrap.php`, an empty module-level bootstrap `Default_Bootstrap` extending `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`.

Then, in a controller, for example:

```
$form = new Default_Form_ManageContent();
```

works for me.